# How to see the source code for an "update!' method

Tags: ruby, debugging, memory-leaks, introspection

I have a web site that is killed due to a memory overflow. It is triggered during a PUT request coming from a users web browser. Unfortunately, the logs are not helpful in this case. I have traced the issue down to this method definition:

```
  # app/controllers/registrations/profiles_controller.rb
  def update
    update! do |success, failure|
      success.html { redirect_to edit_registration_diagnosis_path }
      failure.html do
        build_diagnosis
        render 'edit'
      end
    end
  end
```

I want to see the source code for this `update!` method. How do I ask ruby or rails or bash/grep to show me this source code?

I tried:

```
git grep 'def update!'  # no results
```

My env:
    $ rails --version
    Rails 3.2.22.5
    $ ruby --version
    ruby 1.9.3p551

Comment: What text editor are you using?

Comment: [`activerecord/lib/active_record/persistence.rb`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/persistence.rb#L100), perhaps you want to dig for your current Rails version.

Comment: I'm using whats installed at my clients site (sublime/textedit)

Comment: I doubt `activerecord/lib/active_record/persistence.rb` defines that update! we're looking for. because we're in the context of controller, and active record is a different context (model)

Answer (score 0):

The libraries are not in the same directory as your Rails app, they'll be wherever your Ruby versions are, which differs depending on which version manager you used to install it.

The Rails docs are online at http://api.rubyonrails.org/, or you could use a gem like pry-byebug to step into the method during execution. As Ruby is object oriented and uses an inheritance chain to find an object that responds to a given message, this is the best way to really know which method is being called at any given point in the application's execution.

Add `gem 'pry-byebug'` to your gemfile, bundle install and then insert `binding.pry` at the top of your update method. Once execution pauses you can easily step into the method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use byebug gem to see what is happening at each step in your method.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, the code in your app is not the full set of code that is running. So `grep` won't work here. You may also run into the issue where the same method is defined multiple times, and `grep` won't help there, either.

The best solution I've found is using `pry`. It looks like this is a Rails project, so you can get results most easily by adding the following to your Gemfile:

```
# Gemfile
gem "pry-rails"
gem "pry-doc"
```

At this point, the world is your oyster.

The easiest way to start learning how to use this is to add a `binding.pry` in your code execution where you want to explore. Then run the code in test or development environments, and your server will stop and give you a console at that line. Then you just `show-source update!` and you'll see where the method is defined.

So step 1, use `pry` and explore its many [plugin libraries](https://github.com/pry).

Step 2 is to try out `solargraph` in your text editor. It's not as powerful as `pry`, but it can help you jump to method definitions within your project easily. https://solargraph.org

Step 3 check out the premium text editor RubyMine, as it has support for this sort of thing and much more, though it's not free. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/ruby/getting-started.html